# css divs 2 rows 1 static 1 dynamic height

Tags: css

I have a `<div>`, and I need two divs in it.  One should be 30px tall and
the other should fill in the rest of div (this one will also have overflow)

```
 -----------------
|                 |
 -----------------
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
 -----------------
```

I've tried to do it like this:

```
<style> 
.grayBox{ 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0%; 
    left: 0%; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background-color: black; 
    z-index:1001; 
    -moz-opacity: 0.7; 
    opacity:.70; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=70); 
} 
.box_content { 
    direction:rtl;
    text-align:right;
    position: fixed; 
    top: 25%; 
    left: 25%; 
    right: 25%; 
    width: 50%; 
    height:50%;
//    padding: 16px; 
    z-index:1002; 
    overflow: no; 
} 

.close {
    background-color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:10pt;
    padding-top:5px;
    height:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
}

</style> 

<div id="grayBG" class="grayBox" style="display:none;"></div> 
<div id="LightBox1" class="box_content" style="display:none;">
    <div onclick="displayHideBox('1'); return false;" class="close">סגור</div>
    <div style="overflow:auto; height:100%;">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"> 
        <tr align="right"> 
            <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding:10px;">
                <%
                strSQL="SELECT * FROM tblMainCats WHERE id=50"
                rs.CursorType = 2
                rs.LockType = 3
                rs.Open strSQL, strCon
                %><%=rs("PartContent")%><%
                rs.close
                %>
            </td> 
        </tr> 
    </table> 
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**after what sotiris showed me - here is what i get if i do what you guys said:
http://jsbin.com/ebusu3/3**

Comment: is there any reason why you want to fill the remaining space? is it dynamic content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the height of a div by giving it a top and a bottom and letting the browser figure out the rest.

So:

Top div:

```
{
  position:absolute;
  height:30px;
}
```

Bottom div:

```
{
  position:absolute;
  height:auto;
  top:30px;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: have you checked if this work?! when you give height:auto the height take the height of the content. What is the point of top:30px and bottom:0px?

Comment: Yes it works, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ctrlfrk/drQHw/
I should have included the positioning, because it relies on absolute. I have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use percentage height. If your container has height 300 pixels for example then the top div will have `height:10%;` and the bottom `height:90%;`

To find the height for the top div use the classic formula:

> 3000 (30 pixels * 100) / Your total
>   height

Live example: http://jsbin.com/ebusu3

Comment: this behavoir is logical. You set height for the container 50% (of the screen) and then 100% for the bottom. In the container you have to set fixed height, and then to give the correct percentages for the top and bottom divs. example: http://jsbin.com/ebusu3/4

Comment: Don't do it this way, just change your bottom div to {position:absolute; width:100%; top:30px; bottom:0px} like in here: http://jsfiddle.net/ctrlfrk/drQHw/

Comment: It relies on knowing what the container's height is. And if you know the container's height what is the point of using percentages? Just use 30px for the top and (container's height - 30px) for the base.

Comment: what i ended up doing is similar to David's solution, but hay dave, sotiris can change the height and it will be the same

Answer (score 0):

First Div:

```
{
height: 30px;
}
```

second:

```
{
height: auto;
position: relative;
}
```

in jQuery you can do that:

```
var H = $('#container').outerHeight() - 30;
$('#secondDiv').height() = H;
```

Comment: why someone use javascript when there is a pure css solution?

Comment: in fact there are both solutions... but you can need the javascript solution only sometimes...

Comment: not working for me... still the bottom div with the dynamic contact is getting over the continer div if i add background color or border